# L2TP/IPsec VPN on Chromeos but don't forward all traffic

Tags: networking, vpn, google-chrome-os

I configuered a L2TP/IPsec VPN on a chromebook (version 102) to connect to my company network.

But now all traffic is redirected through the vpn which is a bottleneck for teams and other services.

Prior I used OpenVPN which only used the VPN for my companies remote network.

How can I configure the chromebook to not redirect internet traffic through the vpn?

Comment: You should have several options, either set up a split tunnel manually, use a client with that capability or make the appropriate settings on the server side. There are quite a few resources online, eg. here: https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/7gz63c/split_tunnel_vpn_on_chromeos/dqmyd0j/

Comment: Thanks, `split tunnel` was a good hint to search for. Found this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=476397 TLDR: Not possible via GUI but If I write an `*.onc` file I could use `StaticIPConfig > IncludedRoutes / ExcludedRoutes` I will post an answer if I manged to do it.